# Is it advisable to run a snow blower on a non-GFCI receptacle?

Tags: gfci, outdoor

Is it advisable to run a snow blower on a non-GFCI receptacle?

After all, while using the machine I will always be wearing mittens and boots. Would these not provide sufficient safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather subjective question considering the array of risk factors and variance in individual tolerance for risk.

Most modern electrical tools are double-insulated. This implies a secondary grounding mechanism in case of short to the chassis or housing of the tool. That said, freak incidents do occur, and the possibility exists for you to be shocked. Seeing as you're standing in a sea of frozen water when doing snow removal, it's not accurate to assume that you're fully insulated. Melting snow and sweat can easily provide paths for conductivity.

I suggest a GFCI outlet, but I'd personally not be deterred from doing the job should one be unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

NSIS.  A GFCI receptacle will certainly provide more protection than mittens and boots.  If there isn't a GFCI receptacle available, you can use a portable GFCI

[image: portable GFCI]

on whatever receptacle is available.

Comment: I need to get one of those, just to have it in my toolit. It's a better solution than the kludge I built. But as noted by Isherwood, most modern tools are double-insulatedd and unless you get them soaking wet or cut through the power cord they are supposed to be safe without GFCI.

Answer (score 2):

No, mittens and gloves don't provide adequate safety (insulation) because they get wet and sometimes they slip off or we take them off; or sometimes you might accidentally touch the unit with an un-insulated body part. It is **advisable** to use a GFCI protected power source.